# How to write the Mat/Image to the RTMP stream in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I can open RTSP video stream by using the `VideoCapture` and read the frames.

It is the URL of RTSP stream:

```
rtsp://username:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/Streaming/Channels/102
```

Now I want to send/write the image/mat back to the output stream (RTMP stream over LAN network)

I have already set up the RTMP server which is NGINX, and for a test, I downloaded the [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows), and when running the following command (in CMD) then it works well, and successfully read and write the stream to NGINX server.

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://username:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/Streaming/Channels/102 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv rtmp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1395/mylive/test
```

And now if I put this `rtmp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1395/mylive/test` URL to the `video` tag of `HTML`, then the video can be opened.

**So** the question is how I can push the image through RTMP (NGINX) from my code after processing?

Any suggestion. Thanks in advance!!

**Edit:**

I used `VideoWriter` class as the following ways, but no one was working:

```
VideoWriter writer = new VideoWriter();
writer.open("rtmp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1395/mylive/test", CAP_FFMPEG, 0, 25, 
new Size(640, 480));
//writer.open("ffmpeg -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv 
//rtmp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1395/mylive/test", CAP_FFMPEG, 0, 25, new Size(640, 
//480));
// or without CAP_FFMPEG
if (!writer.isOpened()) {
    System.out.println("open error");
}
```

Comment: Im pretty sure this isn't something built into OpenCV. I think you can use [GStreamer in conjunction with OpenCV](https://github.com/tik0/mat2gstreamer) though

Comment: Finally received a reply :) OK, I will try it. If against any problem, then ask you. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @GPPK I have compiled opencv with GStreamer, now when I try to open the `VideoWiter` with this URL 'rtmp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1395/mylive/test' Or some other, it is not working, and says something like this 'cannot find appsrc in manual pipeline`. So how can I use GStreamer to push/write the frame to the given RTMP pipeline?

Comment: Please ask this as a new question, new questions do not go into the comments of older questions

Comment: I've a question about Gstream and the filters that they're applying to the frames.. Could you check that question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848575/gstreamer-and-frame-image-processing-filtering